# Problems centering thumbnails

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a thumbnails responsive page and it needs to be centered. I define the size of the elements by %. So when I try to center all the content from the container it is not working, since the margin-left from the element on the left has also a % of margin. Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="thumb-container">        
        <div class="clearfix">    
            <a href="" class="thumb-unit"></a>
            <a href="" class="thumb-unit"></a>
            <a href="" class="thumb-unit"></a>
            <a href="" class="thumb-unit"></a>
            <a href="" class="thumb-unit"></a>
            <a href="" class="thumb-unit"></a>
            <a href="" class="thumb-unit"></a>
       </div>                 
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
 .clearfix {
        overflow: auto;}
    .thumb-container {
        width: 92%;
        margin: 0 auto 0;
        padding-top: 67px;  
        +clearfix;}
    .thumb-unit {
        display: block;
        width: 27%;
        padding-top: 35%;
        margin-left: 5.55556%;

        margin-top: 4.33%;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css styles are messy. You can just use just two classes here to get what you wanted. Try this one below.

HTML:

```
<div class="thumb-container">        
        <div class="clearfix">    
            <a href="" class="thumb-unit">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
            </a>
            <a href="" class="thumb-unit">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
            </a>
            <a href="" class="thumb-unit">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
            </a>
            <a href="" class="thumb-unit">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
            </a>
       </div>                 
</div>
```

CSS:
a.thumb-unit {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto }

```
.thumb-container {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        display: flex; /* add */
        justify-content: center; /* add to align horizontal */
        align-items: center; /* add to align vertical */
    }
```

Check the working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/p3ggc8y1/)

Answer (score 0):

You should try a margin of `0 auto` for your `thumb-unit` class. You also have some unnecessary css that you can remove to tidy things up a bit.